# Mi programa se ejecuta más de una vez cuando ingreso datos desde consola

Tags: c, loops

Lo que pasa es que quiero hacer un programa que me diga si el caracter que ingresé es vocal o consonante:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a;
    int w=0;
    while(w<=1)
    {
        printf("\n\nIngresa un caracter:\n");
        scanf("%c",&a);
        if(a=='a'||a=='e'||a=='i'||a=='o'||a=='u'||a=='A'||a=='E'||a=='I'||a=='O'||a=='U')
        {
            printf("La vocal que ingresaste es %c",a);
        }
        else
        {
             printf("La consonante que ingresaste es %c",a);
        }
    }
}
```

Pero al momento de compilar aparece y escribir un caracter el programa hace como si yo pusiera dos enters:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué hago para que esto no pase?
Utilizo gcc como compilador

Comment: Podrias especificar si el problema son los dos enters o que el programa se ejecute infinitamente. Las dos respuestas que te dieron le dan en el clavo, pero son para dos problemas diferentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la funcion scanf interpreta que al presionar enter estas ingresando un nuevo carácter y por eso tu programa se ejecuta nuevamente.

Para solucionarlo rapidamente podrías poner un getchar () luego del scanf para que absorba el enter y debería funcionar.

Otra opción (y bastante más prolija) es agregar la siguiente sentencia antes de cada scanf en tu codigo:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

Esta función se utiliza para limpiar el buffer temporal donde se almacenan las teclas presionadas del teclado al utilizar la función scanf

Comment: Edite la respuesta agregando la posibilidad de resolver el problema con la funcion fflush para no tener que colocar el getchar

Comment: `fflush` **no debe usarse** con dispositivos de salida ya que el resultado es _undefined behaviour_.

Answer (score 1):

Según por lo que veo tu programa se ejecutara hasta que "W" cambie pero dentro de tu *while* ¿Cuándo le indicas que cambie?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a;
    int w=0;
    while(w = 0)
    {
        printf("\n\nIngresa un caracter:\n");
        scanf("%c",&a);
        if(a=='a'||a=='e'||a=='i'||a=='o'||a=='u'||a=='A'||a=='E'||a=='I'||a=='O'||a=='U')
        {
            printf("La vocal que ingresaste es %c",a);
            w = 1; 
        }
        else
        {
             printf("La consonante que ingresaste es %c",a);
        }
    }
}
```

Yo haría esa modificación para que cuando detecte una vocal haga que cambie *W*.

Saludos!

Comment: Hay que ver si quiere salir con la vocal o con la consonante o siempre. igual es un buen aporte